# How to redirect to html after making a ajax POST request in expess.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, express

I have a ajax POST request using express.js. After the request is completed i want to render a html page. But using response.render('ElectronicsCart.html'); is not working. Also since it was a ajax request i tried to redirect it in the success handler of the ajax request using  window.location.href = "ElectronicsCart.html". But it leads to 404 not found error. Please help me fixing this issue.

**Script/Electronic.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $link = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/submitValues',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data.toString()); // for testing
               window.location.href = "ElectronicsCart";
            }
        });

        return false;
    });


});
```

**views/ElectronicsCart**
This is the html being called.

Comment: 404 means the file does not exist at that path

Comment: Is the file that redirecting on the same path/directory of the file being called(ElectronicsCart.html)?

Comment: Adding code would allow us to help you quicker.

Comment: yeah thats true that it is not able to locate the html file but i have tried using the directory/ElectronicsCart.html. The js from which it is called is at Script/Electronic.js

Comment: @Joraid: i have shared the paths...

Comment: ElectronicsCart or ElectronicsCart.html ?